# Retrieve the original content of a webpage that was browsed in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, cache

I browsed a post on Craigslist in Chrome in my Android phone, and after a few hours when I checked the post again using the same URL, the webpage says that the author of the post has deleted the post.

Is there some way to retrieve the original post, for example, from the browser of my phone?

I also googled the URL of the post, but Google only shows the first sentence of the original post in the search result, and the search result doesn't provide a "Cache" option. Is it possible to see the entire post in Google server's cache?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on [View webpages cached in Google Search Results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en)

The gist is:
1. On your computer, do a Google search for the page you want to find.
2. Click the green down arrow to the right of the site's URL.
3. Click Cached.

There also are other sites that do that for you, for instance http://cachedview.com/